# catch error `module must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, progressive-web-apps

### Example

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script type="module">
    import 'someModule'
</script>
```

---

> TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: someModule

---

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "someModule". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

---

### Q:

1. Is it possible to **catch this error**?
2. **Who dispatch** this error?

### Context

In this case, the dependency can be caught and resolved using the service worker.

```html
<script type="module">
    import '/someModule'
</script>
```

Comment: do we need script tag if we want to import module?

Comment: inside html file, just example

Comment: You are not importing it in write way I guess... can you write proper import '/someModule' ??

Comment: I think this is the correct way to import a js-file in html.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile. js"></script>`

Comment: @Natrium he is trying to import a module not a script file.

Comment: `@Natrium` now W3C has a problem with `type='text/javascript'`, at least in their tester. Just leave that off, and fix that filename for a JavaScript file. Maybe you want to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org)?

Comment: looks like I learned something new

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing it in right way as per the error log.

Valid module specifiers must match one of the following:
A full non-relative URL. As in, it doesn't throw an error when put through new URL(moduleSpecifier).

```
Starts with /.
Starts with ./.
Starts with ../.
```

Other specifiers are reserved for future-use, such as importing built-in modules.

Just try this code:

```
<script type="module">
    import {someModule} from './someModule.js';
</script>
```

Comment: You should not use the error code ,rectify it first and then handle error if any.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot catch that error**, unless you use some non-standard uncaught exception handler, like `window.onerror` in browser or `process.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` in Node.js.

Catching that error is impossible because `import` statements are allowed only outside of any blocks, in the module-global scope. Therefore, if you try to wrap the `import` into a `try..catch`, it will throw a SyntaxError.

Instead, you could use the dynamic `import()` syntax proposal, which can be called anywhere; and handle its promise rejection.